# Как сделать, чтобы бот в телеграм (на Python) каждый раз отвечал случайным сообщением из списка?

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot

Хочу сделать простого бота, который будет на каждое новое сообщение пользователя отвечать новой случайной фразой из списка. Но получается так, что отвечает одной и той же.

[image: До Run]

Но после нажатия Run (IDE - комьюнити версия Pycharm) - меняет ответ. И опять только его и повторяет. До следующей такой интерации с нажатием Run.

[image: После Run]

Подскажите, пожалуйста, чего я не знаю?

Бот @lazylazybot

Код:

*main.py*

```html
import telebot
import constants

bot = telebot.TeleBot(constants.token)

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def handle_start(message):
     bot.send_message(message.chat.id, constants.startAnswer)

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def handle_text(message):
     bot.send_message(message.chat.id, constants.otmazka)

if __name__ == '__main__':
     bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

*constants.py*

```html
import random

token = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"

startAnswer = "Привет! Я придумываю оправдания для лени! Пришли, что тебе нужно делать."
otmazki = ['Не сегодня','Завтра','Лучше отдохнуть','Работа не волк','Еще куча времени']
otmazka = random.choice(otmazki)
```

Comment: random на самом деле никакой не рандом. И каждый раз при старте приложения (если ничего не сделать), он будет генерировать одну и ту же последовательность.  Добавьте вызов `random.seed()` где то в начало программы.

Comment: @KoVadim неверно

Comment: Попробуйте, `random_message = lambda: random.choice(messages)`, а чтобы получит сообщение для отправки: `random_message()` (обратите внимание на скобочки). Кто-нибудь может написать ответ о разнице между строкой (константа) и функцией (каждый вызов может новое значение вернуть).

Comment: @jfs спасибо, получилось!

Comment: @Jul [вы можете свой ответ оставить](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Comment: @jfs +++сделано

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Получился бот, который помогает лениться:)

[image: lazylazybot]

Как всё получилось:

constants.py

```html
import random

token = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"

startAnswer = "Привет! Я придумываю оправдания для лени! Напиши мне, что тебе нужно делать."
otmazki = ['Не сегодня', 'Каждая лень имеет свою причину. Займись чем-то примитивным.', 'Чтобы обленить тело, надо как можно меньше пользоваться умом и жить только здесь и сейчас.', 'Насладиться ленью по-настоящему может лишь тот, у кого есть куча совершенно неотложных дел. С каждой секундой наслаждение растет.','Завтра','Лучше отдохнуть','Работа не волк','Еще куча времени', 'Это не так важно','Зачем себя пересиливать','Тебе это не нужно на самом деле','Полежать всегда лучше','Ютуб сам себя не посмотрит','Лучше подрочить','Всё равно все тлен']
random_message = lambda: random.choice(otmazki)
```

main.py

```html
import telebot
import constants

bot = telebot.TeleBot(constants.token)

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def handle_start(message):
     bot.send_message(message.chat.id, constants.startAnswer)

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def handle_text(message):
         bot.send_message(message.chat.id, constants.random_message())

if __name__ == '__main__':
     bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```